# Not able to start ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

When even run activemq cmd, getting below lines but server is not starting.

Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_131 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1005056k  free=989327k  max=1005056k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\conf;D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin../conf;D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin../conf; -Dactivemq.home=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin.. -Dactivemq.base=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin.. -Dactivemq.conf=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\conf -Dactivemq.data=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\lib,D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\lib\camel,D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\lib\optional,D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\lib\web,D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: D:\Apache ActiveMq\apache-activemq-5.14.5\bin..\data
Usage: Main [--extdir ] [task] [task-options] [task data]

Tasks:
    browse                   - Display selected messages in a specified destination.
    bstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays useful statistics regarding the specified broker
    consumer                 - Receives messages from the broker
    create                   - Creates a runnable broker instance in the specified path.
    decrypt                  - Decrypts given text
    dstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays useful tabular statistics regarding the specified destination type
    encrypt                  - Encrypts given text
    export                   - Exports a stopped brokers data files to an archive file
    list                     - Lists all available brokers in the specified JMX context
    producer                 - Sends messages to the broker
    purge                    - Delete selected destination's messages that matches the message selector
    query                    - Display selected broker component's attributes and statistics.
    start                    - Creates and starts a broker using a configuration file, or a broker URI.
    stop                     - Stops a running broker specified by the broker name.

Task Options (Options specific to each task):
    --extdir   - Add the jar files in the directory to the classpath.
    --version       - Display the version information.
    -h,-?,--help    - Display this help information. To display task specific help, use Main [task] -h,-?,--help

Task Data:
    - Information needed by each specific task.

JMX system property options:
    -Dactivemq.jmx.url= (default is: 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi')
    -Dactivemq.jmx.user=
    -Dactivemq.jmx.password=

Comment: What version? On what OS?

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in the video and able to start ActiveMq                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaegBVoVvlQ                                            Thanks....